# how to modify a column of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to make a characteristic function like : I have a tensor X, if X[:,i]>1 then X[:,i]=0 else X[:,i]=1. But I want to conserve the shape of X

I have already tried several reshaping but I can't find the very same shape of X after unstack X and change the value of the list

```py
def g_tf(self, t,X):

        x_unpacked = tf.unstack(X,num=None,axis=1)
        processed = []
        for little_x in x_unpacked: 
          tensor_10= tf.cast(tf.constant([1.0])[None, None], tf.float64)
          tensor_1=tf.reshape(tensor_10, tf.shape(x_petit))

          bool=tf.greater(little_x, tensor_1, name=None)
          bool_reshape= tf.reshape(boule, [])
          result_tensor= tf.cond(boule_reshape, lambda: tf.constant(1),lambda: tf.constant(0))
          processed.append(result_tensor)
        output=tf.stack(processed, 0) 
        print(output) #Tensor("forward/stack:0", shape=(50,), dtype=int32)
        Output__=tf.cast(output, dtype =tf.float64 )
        X_new=X  # Shape of X :  shape=(?, 50), dtype=float64)

        print(X_new[1])  #Tensor("forward/strided_slice_190:0", shape=(50,), dtype=float64)

        X_new= X_new[1].assign(Output__)  #They have the same shape : shape=(50,)

        final_op= tf.reduce_sum(X_new,1, keepdims=True)                    
        return final_op
```

`ValueError:` Tried to convert 'input' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.
this error occurs on the line :  `X_new= X_new[1].assign(Output__)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got what you're trying to do here right. I don't really follow what you're doing here. But the following solution should work for what you're trying to achieve.

For example if you have the array `[[2,3], [1,0], [0,0]]` you want the output to be `[[1,1],[0,0],[0,0]]`. Hope I got it right. If this is what you need following should work.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# some random dataset
x = tf.random.normal(shape=(5,10),mean=2.0, stddev=0.5)

# Getting the colums of the data
x_unpack = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)

processed =[]
for x_col in x_unpack:
  ones = tf.ones_like(x_col)
  # Checks if all values in x_col are greater than one
  cond_tensor = tf.reduce_all(tf.greater(x_col, ones)) 
  # Get the resulting column
  res = tf.cond(cond_tensor, lambda: tf.ones_like(x_col),lambda: tf.zeros_like(x_col)) 
  processed.append(res)

out = tf.stack(processed, axis=1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(out))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much ! It's work and it's exactly what i wanted to do

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer please accept it as the correct answer :)

Comment: sorry this was my very first question here, now it's done ! :)